# Distance between an arc and a straight line

Tags: geometry

What equation would I use to find the distance between any point on the arc to line A knowing the angle relative to line A? Let's say the distance from the 90° angle is 8.5.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWXwk.jpg)

Comment: Your arc seems to be a circular arc. Please provide details such as the center (perhaps the origin for convenience?) and the radius would be helpful, as would the equation of line $A$ (or two points on it, from which the equation is easily found).

Comment: the distance will be minimized at the point that the tangent to the arc is parallel to the line.  Or the normal to the arc is perpendicular to the line.  If you have a circular arc, the radius is perpendicular to the line.  Construct a line from the center of the circle to the line that is perpendicular to the line.  Get this distance and subtract the radius.

Comment: It is a circle. The radius is 40.5, and when the radius is 90° to line A it is 8.5" away

Comment: I am looking for an equation to find the distance from any moving point along the arc to line A.

Comment: Assume the line to be the x axis and write the equation of the circle - the y value will be the distance

Comment: Doug and Moti, I am obviously making this harder than it is. I started out trying to find the tangent although line A doesn't touch the arc at any point. Along the was I got a mental block. What equation am I looking for? I drew it on graph paper and found the distances for the 3 points, but I can't for the life of me come up with the equation to back into my answers.